# Won't x = x + 5 in Javascript be a deadlock?

Tags: javascript, variables

I am learning Javascript from W3Schools and I am in Assignment Operator (=) section.

It says that x = x + 5 in Javascript makes perfect sense, but I don't understand how...

Suppose we assigned a value of 5 to x, then the equation above will be 5 = 10?

It also says that the "equal to" operator is written like == in JavaScript, but the function below gives a correct answer 11 without ==

```
<script>
var price1 = 5;
var price2 = 6;
var total = price1 + price2;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
"The total is: " + total;
</script>
```

This is twisting my mind. Can you guys please help me? I don't want to proceed further before I have all the basics cleared.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Evaluation order.

Comment: This is not mathematics, it is programming. You have to understand the order of command execution. And W3Schools is not a good resource for that.

Comment: It is an assignment of a value to a variable

Comment: Operator precedence states that `+` is higher in precedence than `=`. So `x + 5` get calculated first, then `x = the result` next.

Comment: Thankfully the expression is only evaluated once.

Comment: No, `x = x + 5` means assign the value `5 + 5  (10)` to x. Read more about Assignment operator(`=`) vs Equality operator(`==`).

Comment: I like the way you think :)

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for taking the time to answer my silly question. Looks like I chose a wrong resource to study Javascript. Will go through Operator Precedence before I proceed.

Comment: A lot of downvotes (and one close) for this. But this is a valid beginner question: many tutorials fail to explain the basics leading to confusion like this where symbols from one area of human endeavour have a different meaning in another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thinking process is not right;

When you do;

```
x = x + 5
```

Then, first **x+5** is evaluated.

After that the value is assigned to the left hand side variable. So in left hand side whether it is **x** or something else does not matter.

This is similar to;

```
p = x + 5
x = p
```

This case is not for Javascript but almost for all languages.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it in such a lucid way Sir.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript (and many other programming languages) the `=` operator in expressions is not about equality, rather it is *assignment*.

So

```
x = x + 5;
```

is *assign to x the result of calculating `x+5`*. The precedence of operators ensures the addition is performed first so this works.

Programming, while having mathematical roots,<sup>1</sup> is not about equations but *expressions* which are evaluated according to the specific rules of the language.

---

<sup>1</sup> This applies to *imperative* languages; there is another branch in programming – *functional* – where things are much closer to mathematics, but JavaScript belongs to the former set.<sup>2</sup>

<sup>2</sup> Of course there is a lot of borrowing one way and the other to confuse the issue.

Comment: To mitigate this confusion (I presume), some languages use a different operator, such as `:=`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes. Hence C family languages like JavaScript have `==` for equality. Of course with JS being dynamic there is need for strict equality as well, hence `===`.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation about [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) you can see in the table that `+` (13-Addition) will be evaluated before `=` (3- Assignment)

Thus it will first evaluate `x+5` which is `10` then it will assign 10 to `x`